# How did Vishnu become Shaligrama Stone?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, shaligrama

Shaligrama is the most sacred stone for Vaishnavas.

There is a story thus of **Tulasi cursing Vishnu to become a stone** when He polluted Her Chastity to kill Her husband.

***What is the story of Vishnu becoming stone Shaligrama.***

Comment: Are you answering your question? What you mentioned in question is one fo the reasons.

Comment: Related [Did a devotee curse Lord Vishnu to turn into a stone?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20017/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer it was just mention for additional information. If other sources are found then please answer.

Comment: Why is this tagged Vaishnavism? It is not a Vaishnavism question. It is about a story and should be tagged with mythology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story is found in the Devi BhAgavatam for example.

Lord Vishnu has to take away the chastity of Tulasi, the wife of Shankhachuda. And which he did and when Tulasi discovered that out, she cursed him to be turned into a stone.

> 12-13. O Thou, the Ocean of mercy! Now tell me of your heroic valour,
>   how you have come out victorious in war with Mahâdeva who destroys
>   countless universes. **Hearing Tulasî’s word, the Lord of Laksmî, in the
>   guise of S’ankhachûda,** spoke these nectar-like words with a smiling
>   countenance. 14-17. O Dear! Full one Samvatsara the war lasted betwixt
>   us. All the Daityas were killed. Then Brahmâ Himself came and
>   mediated. Peace, then, was brought about and by the command of Brahmâ,
>   I gave over to the Devas their rights. When I returned to my home,
>   S’iva went back to His S’ivaloka. Thus saying, Hari, the Lord of the
>   world, slept and then engaged in sexual intercourse with her. **But the
>   chaste Tulasî, finding this time her experience quite different from
>   what She used to enjoy before, argued all the time within herself and
>   at last questioned him :--**
>
> 18-22. Who are you? O Magician! By spreading your magic, you have
>   enjoyed me. **As you have taken my chastity, I will curse you**. Bhagavân
>   Nârâyana, hearing Tulasî’s words and being afraid of the curse,
>   assumed His real beautiful figure. The Devî then saw the Eternal Lord
>   of the Devas before her. He was of a deep blue colour like fresh
>   rain-clouds and with eyes like autumnal lotuses and with playful Lîlâs
>   equivalent to tens and tens of millions of Love personified and
>   adorned with jewels and ornaments. His face was smiling and gracious;
>   and he wore his yellow-coloured robe. The love-stricken Tulasî, seeing
>   That Lovely Form of Vâsudeva, immediately fell senseless; and at the
>   next moment, regaining consciousness, she began to speak. 23-27. O
>   Lord! Thou art like a stone. Thou hast no mercy. By hypocrisy Thou
>   hast destroyed my chastity, my virtue and for that reason didst kill
>   my husband. O Lord! Thou had no mercy; Thy heart is like a stone. **So
>   Let Thee be turned into a stone.**

And, finally Lord Vishnu accepts the curse. And these ShaligrAma stones are found in the Gandaki river bed in Nepal, as is quite well known.

> **And as for Me, I will be turned into stone by your curse; I will remain in India close to the bank of the river Gandakî.** Millions and
>   millions of insects with their sharp teeth will make rings, (the
>   convolutions in the S’âlagrâma or sacred stones), on the cavities of
>   the mountains there, representing Me.

**Source- [Devi BhAgavatam-Book 9-Chapter 24.](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam49-4.htm)**

BTW, you should also read the chapters previous to this one, which describe why Shankachuda was invincible and why all of this was needed.

Comment: Is this story found in Vishnu purana?

Comment: @AnubhavJha I am not sure if it's found in that puarna or not but might be found in some other puranas.

Comment: how can such a major story about Lord Vishnu not found in Vishnu purana?

Comment: @DOWNVOTERS kindly mention reasons, or add your own answers.

Comment: salagrama is very sacred to vaishnavites.  isn't the padmanabhaswmi idol made of salagrama stones?  it would be astounding if mainstream vaishnavite puranas don;t have their own version of the salagrama story

Comment: @AnubhavJha What more than this that even Shiva Puraana contains story of ShaliGraama. But it is quite a wonder to see that Vishnu Puraana and Bhagwata Puraana seem not to mention Shaligrama.