# Why Saligram is considered symbol of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, symbolism

We can understand that Shiva linga/lingum depicts entire universe or to say existence. But, Saligram is a fossile of a creature of a type Ammonite. What could be the possible reason behind considering ammonite fossil as symbol of lord Vishnu?

Also, it is said that Saligram found at Gandaki River are the only real Saligram used for worship of lord Vishnu? So, all other Ammonite fossils found across the world are not considered Saligram?

Comment: Because it is so mentioned in the scriptures ...

Comment: @Rickross scripts are not mere commands. They always have some reason behind it.

Comment: There is a story given in the Puranas as to how and why Lord Vishnu assumed the form of a Sila. You can find that story on this site as well. That is the reason why and there are no other reasons.

Comment: @Rickross "Sila" means stone, and stones are not fossils. I mean, you can't say "coal" as a stone or dinosaur can't be put into category of stone. So, "Sila" and "Saligram" are two entirely different things.

Comment: Its called Shaligrama Sila.

Comment: @Rickross any naturally calcified dead animals or even diamonds can be put into category of stones. I got your point, but there has to be an explanation to why Saligram which was a living sea creature, now fossilized, was taken as a symbol of lord Vishnu.

Comment: Related or Possibly a duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24583/how-did-vishnu-become-shaligrama-stone/24584

Comment: @Rickross I checked the answer. Thank you! But, it accepts the thought that saligram is a stone. Whereas, I am asking why ammonite fossil was selected as symbol of Vishnu. Reason behind it. Like we have reason behind linga.

Comment: Because the ammonite shell resembles the chakra, which is the main symbol of Bhagavâna Nârâyana.

Comment: @AnubrataBit You mean to say it is just symbolic in nature? If so, then they are not auspicious at all as anything that resembles something in our religion is consider auspicious. Then there is no logic or reasoning to our spirituality or religion. The correct answer is- "We don't know".

Comment: If you know the answer, then why ask it ?

Comment: @AnubrataBit I got to know about this answer "We don't know" after I inquired here.